# How to wait for cookie to get updated in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, playwright

I am working on writing an automated test case using Playwright where I need to wait for cookie to get updated and then perform the next action. Is there any way by which I can wait for a cookie value to update in Javascript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a waiting time with playwright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71189141/how-to-add-a-waiting-time-with-playwright)

Comment: If the above comment did not help and as I don't think there is anything you can listen to on a cookie update, you can just ask every so miliseconds if the value is not what it was and continue if so.